# Heisenberg group deformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, deformation-quantization

I was wondering if there are some relations between deformations within small parameters and the Heisenberg group operation.

We can think about the Heisenberg group $\mathbb{H_3}$ as $(\mathbb{R^3}, \star)$ since it has only $3$ independent parameters, and the binary internal law is given by $(x,y,z) \star (x',y',z') = (x+x',y+y',z+z'+ xy')\\ \forall (x,y,z),(x',y',z') \in \mathbb{R^3} $

In the last term of the operation there is the term $xy'$ which kills the commutativity of the group operation. Is there a possibility to think that this operation derives from a particular type of deformation (maybe small parameter deformation, perturbative deformation) of the usual sum? If yes can this operation assume some physical impact maybe for coupling terms?

Comment: Do you know of the corresponding [Heisenberg Lie algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heisenberg+Lie+algebra)?

Comment: yes I know it!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I am understanding the quest, but, in plain phase space (*q,p*) with the standard Groenewold(-Moyal) star product, and arbitrary deformation parameter, here taken to be *i*, your construct is isomorphic to the plain undeformed [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#On_symplectic_vector_spaces)---note the transformation connecting to your formulation of the central element parameter increment.

So, then, for  $q\star p - p\star q=1$, 
$$
e_\star^{xq+yp+z}\star e_\star^{x'q+y'p+z'} = e_\star ^{(x+x')q+(y+y')p+z+z'+(y'x-x'y)/2} 
$$
Where, of course, the star-exponential is defined in the usual way, $e_\star^f= 1+f+f\star f/2!+ f\star f \star f /3!+...$, replicating the standard combinatorics. This is of course not a deformation of the Heisenberg group, it *is* the Heisenberg group realized on phase space, if we are using the same star product. The WP article redefinitions, shifting  *z* by *xy*/2, may serve, mutatis mutandis, to recast the group law into the variant you are using.